# SQL insert into specialization table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have table Person(idPerson int PK, Name varchar(20)) and i have child table Employee(idPerson int PK, Workplace varchar(20), idPerson reference Person(idPerson)).
Is it possible direct insert into table Employee, or i need first to insert into table Person, and then insert into Empolyee with correspond idPerson?
How can i do that insert with procedure and transactions?

Comment: What `RDBMS` are you using? `mysql` is not the same as `sql-server`.

Comment: Hey, It simple Wait i give store procedure..

Comment: @PeterAbolins I use mySql. Sorry, i m new in data bases, i m in stage of learning.

Answer (score 0):

try this store procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[abcInsert]
    @idPerson INT ,
    @Name VARCHAR(255) = 'abc',
    @work VARCHAR (50)='abcb'
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON                        


    BEGIN                


        INSERT  INTO dbo.Person WITH ( ROWLOCK )
                ( Name )
        VALUES  ( @Name )           

        DECLARE @ID INT                  

        SET @ID = @@IDENTITY    

        INSERT  INTO dbo.Employee WITH ( ROWLOCK )
                ( idPerson, Workplace )
        VALUES  ( @ID, @work )          



    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a declared foreign key relationship between the two tables, then you need a valid `idPerson` when you do the insert.

The one exception would be if you had a `NULL` or other (valid) default value.  However, you have also declared `idPerson` as the primary key, so it cannot be `NULL`.

Hence, the answer to your question is that you need to insert into `Person` before inserting into `Employee`.  That is how you have declared the data model.